# Rough edges on mesh in final render[cycles]

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I made a car in blender and added some materials to it. I also downloaded a background image and set it as a background along with some node editing. But in my final render, the car has rough and jaggy edges, mainly in the top right area. Is there a problem with my nodesettings, or on my mesh?
[image: Look at the highlighted region.It is not smooth.]

[image]
The node which is not fully visible (see on the top of the picture) is a mix node.

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) and edit your question with the provided link?

Comment: can you plz upload an image of the node copositor?
is this blender render? or cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

...you could start by clicking anti-alias in both the ID Masks....